# MQTT protocol implementation in android Asynchronously

Tags: android, mqtt

I am new to MQTT protocol implementation in android. Currently I am using Android Studio. I have gone through the  [Eclipse Paho link](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/)(https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) but I found only Synchronous Connection Example.  Here my Question is:

1. How to implement the MQTTAsyncClient with a call back ?
2. Do we have to persist the connection along with callback throughout the application to get the messages from server at anytime ?

Please help me